# Как отправить сообщения пользователю с уведомлением через Aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Допустим я хочу отправить сообщение пользователю:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(1234567890, "Hello!")
```

Но не приходит уведомление от бота. Я попробовал дать третий аргумент `disable_notifications = False` но не помогло. Как это решить? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: пользователь которому хотите отправить авторизовался в этом боте?

Comment: Да. Сообщение приходит но уведомлений нет

Comment: зайдите в настройки в чате с ботом и включите уведомления.

Comment: Включено. В телефон приходит. Но на комп не приходит